# Migrate SCOM 2007 R2 Databases to SQL 2008 R2 (change server)

Tags: migration, sql-server-2008-r2, scom, sql-server

**UPDATE**
I have a SCOM 2007 R2 server that uses a sql 2005 server.

Machine 1: SCOM (SCOM 2007 R2 - W2K3)
Machine 2: SQL2005 (SQL 2005 SP2 - W2K3)
SQL Cluster: SQLCLUSTER (SQL 2008 R2 on Cluster - W2K8R2)
Reporting Services is on one of the cluster machines as it's not cluster aware.

I Currently use SQL2005 for OperationsManager, OperationsManagerDW db, and Reporting services.

I need to know how to migrate All this (Including Reporting Services) to the cluster.

Reinstalling is not an option since I don't know how to do this, and don't want to lose data.

Microsoft released the SCOM 2007 R2 CU 4 that does support Migration to SQL 2008 R2.

I Found [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2425714) from MS that points to [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2449679) that does suport SQL 2008 R2: and I've successfully updated SCOM 2007 R2 to CU 4.

I've found [this tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/kevinholman/archive/2011/02/01/opsmgr-2007-r2-cu4-rollup-hotfix-ships-and-my-experience-installing-it.aspx) on updating SCOM 2007 R2 to CU 4 and followed it:

[This KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2449679) says:
The feature for SQL Server 2008 database update support lets you upgrade a database for SCOM 2007 R2 to SQL Server 2008 R2. The tools for this feature are in the SupportTools folder of the update package. For more information about how to upgrade a database from SCOM 2007 R2, visit the following Microsoft TechNet article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789004.aspx

In the following upgrade scenarios, follow the steps that are described on the "How to update a database from SCOM 2007 R2" TechNet website:
SQL Reporting Services 2005 to SQL Reporting Services 2008 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
SQL Reporting Services 2008 Service Pack 1 (SP1) to SQL Reporting Services 2008 R2

So I guess I have to upgrade to SQL 2008, and then I'll be able to migrate to SQL 2008 R2, however I already have a SQL 2008 R2 Cluster and want to simply add this databases and reporting services there, if anyone have info on this I would gladly apreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SCOM 2007 R2 still does not support SQL 2008 R2 for existing installations. The latest cumulative update for SCOM (CU#3) was just released November 15 and didn't include support, so you will have a while to wait for a CU to cover it. You may be able to contact Microsoft Support and see if a hotfix is available through that route instead.

Comment: As far as i read about CU#3 it does support SQL 2008 R2 but not clean installation but an upgrade.

Comment: @MadBoy: can you clarify that a bit? My understanding was still that it supports SQL08R2 for new installations of SCOM, but not for existing installations. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309428.aspx (but it is dated before CU#3 came out), but also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2251525 - doesn't mention 2008 R2 support at all.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/operationsmanagerdeployment/thread/4e10d747-0ebb-4b19-bdaf-50b3ce679844) and this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/operationsmanagerdeployment/thread/cccd68b9-053b-406d-b4e5-6dfedf65b713) it seems the official saying is it's not supported but there are couple of workarounds given if you would like to go that route. However it seems there is now official way to do so, which I found out by digging it for you: [Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/momteam/archive/2010/09/28/om2007r2-support-for-sql-2008-r2.aspx) and [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2425714)

And I could swear I saw somewhere on CU3 installation tips that upgrade is now possible (and was even advice to go upgrade way then clean way - by the blogger). I'll try to find the link and update if so.

Comment: Thanks @MadBoy, I found that KB too, and somewhere on the web I noticed that someone performed a upgrade on the SQL machine from SQL 2005 to 2008 R2 without touching the SCOM 2007 R2, and they say it worked.